# php sessions using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

hi im trying to write an enquiry form in php where it gets values from a session array.. but ive cant think how to start.. what im thinking is say for example ive got a page with items on and i click add to enquiry list it will then post it to the enquiry page using ajax? can anyone give me a push start?

cheers

Comment: The best push ever: make it without AJAX first.

Answer (score 1):

You shall pass sessions variables to your AJAX requests in the form of (javascript code):

```
enquiry.php?' + session_name + '='  + session_id + '&add=whaevere_you_want&foo=bar
```

Where **session_name** and **session_id** are javascript local variables obtained via AJAX initalizer to fetch them from a php script which is capable of providing them via PHP functions:

```
session_name()
session_id()
```

respectively